# Enable TLS/SSL on postfix

Tags: postfix

I am working on a postfix server which only sends mails (newsletters).

I have read i should enable TLS and/or SSL on postfix in order to increase mail deliverability performance. Is it true ?

Is there a difference between SSL and TLS under postfix ?

I already have this 2 lines by default on my postfix installation:

```
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
```

So i am wondering if ssl is already enabled by default ? What are this auto-generated pem and key files ?

Is it a good thing to replace them by my https certificate ? (i already have an https certificate for my domain. Is is the same kind of certificates for postfix and nginx) ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postfix's `smtpd_tls...` and `smtpd_use_tls` settings refer to use of SSL/TLS only when Postfix is acting as a server (i.e. when other things are making connections *to* Postfix).

To use SSL/TLS when Postfix is sending mails *out*, you'll need to configure the corresponding `smtp_tls...` parameters (note: `smtp_` without the `d`).

SSL is the obsolete predecessor of TLS. They are very similar and TLS *can* be backwards compatible to SSL, although by now essentially all the SSL versions are known to have security weaknesses, and you should only use/accept TLS (ideally TLS 1.2 or greater).

The `ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem` and its corresponding key file `ssl-cert-snakeoil.key` is a self-signed "dummy" certificate that will not be trusted by anyone else unless they choose to configure their systems to trust that particular certificate. A real certificate from a well-known Certificate Authority will be much better than that, assuming that the certificate doesn't have any extensions that might make it invalid for SMTP use (your https certificate will probably work just fine for you).

Yes, the certificate for Postfix is basically the same kind as a certificate for nginx, Apache or any similar web server.

The use of a valid certificate with SMTP indicates that you have committed at least some amount of time & money towards your server's electronic identity, so it probably will have *some* positive contribution to anti-spam scores when receiving mail servers evaluate your emails. So yes, it may do some good, but I'm not sure how much exactly.

Comment: Is there a way for me to check, in my gmail inbox for example if an inbox mail has been sent to me with TLS or not ?

Comment: You'll need to be able to view the full headers of the email. Each server will add a `Received:` header to the email as it passes through the server, documenting the time it arrived, the source IP address, and (possibly) whether or not TLS/SSL was used.

Comment: I have tried to enable TLS with smtp_tls_security_level=encrypt, smtp_enforce_tls=yes, smtp_tls_cert_file and smtp_tls_key_file. It works great ! I can see this in Received header: (using TLSv1.2 with cipher ADH-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)). But i see a line with: (No client certificate requested). I think this is because of my destination mail service. Do you know a mail service which checks TLS certificate ? I want to be sure my configuration is OK. Thanks